# MVC-4 Route Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have route as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SettingsRoute",
            url: "Settings/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Settings", action = "Index" }
            );
```

But it is not working. When I add any letter after "Settings/", it works.

To give an example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SettingsRoute",
            url: "Settings/x", // or "Settings/q" or "Settings/z"
            defaults: new { controller = "Settings", action = "Index" }
            );
```

It is working.

What I have doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: try like this : `routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SettingsRoute",
            url: "Settings/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Settings", action = "Index" }
            );`

Comment: It does not have much to do with that. But I tried it, didn't work as I expect.

Comment: What does your controller look like? And is this the only route registered or are there more?

Comment: There are approximately 20 more routes. Here is my controller:
    
    public class SettingsController : SecureController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
          return View();
        }
    }

Comment: It's probably to do with your other routes, can you post them?

Comment: I have so many routes. I can't post them all but I checked them for 10 times, and there is no conflict routes.